# What cases of potential obstruction are described in the Mueller report?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, mueller-investigation

The two main issues investigated by Mueller with regard to Trump seem to be conspiracy and obstruction of justice.

We already have a [question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/40790/does-the-mueller-report-show-a-conspiracy-between-russia-and-the-trump-campaign) here which deals with the conspiracy issue.

What about obstruction? How many cases of obstruction by Trump or his campaign are described in the Mueller report, which of these are new information, and what is the given evidence?

Comment: If all you wanted was a big quote from the report... I'm sure you knew where to find that.

Comment: @Fizz I didn't look into the obstruction part of the report (it's a 400+ page report after all), so that was indeed helpful; but I also appreciated your CNN and Slate quotes regarding new information. I'm also still open to other answers.

Comment: @Fizz note also that we're not just here to answer Tim but also the thousands of other people who (have) visit(ed) other questions tagged [mueller-investigation] as of late. While I'm sure Tim will eventually find the executive summaries in the report, many other people won't bother. Even those who are interested will likely only ever read second hand accounts by media outlets and here we have the opportunity to make the original text accessible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Interpretation by PBS

I have found a list similar to the one posted by Fizz, the list is compiled by PBS and contains eleven 'moments Mueller investigated for obstruction of justice'. In addition to the list posted by Fizz, [PBS also mentions](https://www.pbs.org/newshour/politics/11-moments-mueller-investigated-for-obstruction-of-justice):

> - What Trump knew and what he denied about Russia and WikiLeaks (pages 228-236).
> - Did the president try to cover up Michael Flynn’s phone calls with the Russian ambassador or protect him from prosecution? (pages 237-259)
> - Trump’s repeated urging of top administration officials to deny he was under investigation (pages 260- 273)

#### Directly from the Mueller report

Given the discrepancies between those lists, it might be worth looking at what the Mueller report itself says about the matter. Luckily, the Mueller report summarises just that in the first part of the executive summary to volume II, titled *Factual Results of the Obstruction Investigation*. The key issues and events (starting on page 3 of the second volume, page 215 in the linked pdf) as stated in that summary are posted below.

For each of the counts, I will add the full explanation from the summary. Initially, I tried to quote a sentence (or two) to condense it a bit further but that's basically cherry-picking as everything in the summary is already written in as few words as can be. I added extra line breaks where appropriate.

> **Factual Results of the Obstruction Investigation**
>
> The key issues and events we examined include the following:
>
> 1. The Campaign’s response to reports about Russian support for Trump
>
>    - During the 2016
>        about any further planned WikiLeaks
>        presidential campaign, questions arose about the Russian government’s apparent support for
>        candidate Trump. After WikiLeaks released politically damaging Democratic Party emails that
>        were reported to have been hacked by Russia, Trump publicly expressed skepticism that Russia
>        was responsible for the hacks at the same time that he and other Campaign officials privately
>        sought information [redacted; harm to ongoing matter]
>        releases.
>       Trump also denied having any business in or connections to Russia, even though as late
>        as June 2016 the Trump Organization had been pursuing a licensing deal for a skyscraper to be
>        built in Russia called Trump Tower Moscow. After the election, the President expressed concerns
>        to advisors that reports of Russia’s election interference might lead the public to question the
>        legitimacy of his election.
> 2. Conduct involving FBI Director Comey and Michael Flynn.
>
>    - In mid-January 2017,
>        incoming National Security Advisor Michael Flynn falsely denied to the Vice President, other
>        administration officials, and FBI agents that he had talked to Russian Ambassador Sergey Kislyak
>        about Russia’s response to U.S. sanctions on Russia for its election interference. On January 27,
>        the day after the President was told that Flynn had lied to the Vice President and had made similar
>        statements to the FBI, the President invited FBI Director Comey to a private dinner at the White
>        House and told Comey that he needed loyalty. On February 14, the day after the President
>        requested Flynn’s resignation, the President told an outside advisor,
>        “Now that we fired Flynn, the
>        Russia thing is over.
>        ” The advisor disagreed and said the investigations would continue.
>        
>        Later that afternoon, the President cleared the Oval Office to have a one-on-one meeting
>        with Comey. Referring to the FBI’s investigation of Flynn, the President said,
>        “I hope you can
>        see your way clear to letting this go, to letting Flynn go. He is a good guy. I hope you can let this
>        go.” Shortly after requesting Flynn’s resignation and speaking privately to Comey, the President
>        sought to have Deputy National Security Advisor K.T. McFarland draft an internal letter stating
>        that the President had not directed Flynn to discuss sanctions with Kislyak. McFarland declined
>        because she did not know whether that was true, and a White House Counsel’s Office attorney
>        thought that the request would look like a quid pro quo for an ambassadorship she had been offered.
> 3. The President’s reaction to the continuing Russia investigation.
>
>    - In February 2017,
>        Attorney General Jeff Sessions began to assess whether he had to recuse himself from campaign-related investigations because of his role in the Trump Campaign. In early March, the President
>        told White House Counsel Donald McGahn to stop Sessions from recusing. And after Sessions
>        announced his recusal on March 2, the President expressed anger at the decision and told advisors
>        that he should have an Attorney General who would protect him. That weekend, the President
>        took Sessions aside at an event and urged him to “unrecuse.” 
>        Later in March, Comey publicly disclosed at a congressional hearing that the FBI was investigating “the Russian government’s
>        efforts to interfere in the 2016 presidential election,” including any links or coordination between
>        the Russian government and the Trump Campaign.
>       In the following days, the President reached
>        out to the Director of National Intelligence and the leaders of the Central Intelligence Agency
>        (CIA) and the National Security Agency (NSA) to ask them what they could do to publicly dispel
>        the suggestion that the President had any connection to the Russian election-interference effort.
>        The President also twice called Comey directly, notwithstanding guidance from McGahn to avoid
>        direct contacts with the Department of Justice. Comey had previously assured the President that
>        the FBI was not investigating him personally, and the President asked Comey to “lift the cloud”
>        of the Russia investigation by saying that publicly.
> 4. The President’s termination of Comey.
>
>    - On May 3, 2017, Comey testified in a
>        congressional hearing, but declined to answer questions about whether the President was
>        personally under investigation. Within days, the President decided to terminate Comey. The
>        President insisted that the termination letter, which was written for public release, state that Comey
>        had informed the President that he was not under investigation. The day of the firing, the White
>        House maintained that Comey’s termination resulted from independent recommendations from the
>        Attorney General and Deputy Attorney General that Comey should be discharged for mishandling
>        the Hillary Clinton email investigation.
>       But the President had decided to fire Comey before
>        hearing from the Department of Justice. The day after firing Comey, the President told Russian
>        officials that he had “faced great pressure because of Russia,
>        ” which had been “taken off’ by
>        Comey’s firing. The next day, the President acknowledged in a television interview that he was
>        going to fire Comey regardless of the Department of Justice’s recommendation and that when he
>        “decided to just do it,
>        ” he was thinking that “this thing with Trump and Russia is a made-up story.
>        ”
>        In response to a question about whether he was angry with Comey about the Russia investigation,
>        the President said,
>        “As far as I’m concerned, I want that thing to be absolutely done properly,
>        ”
>        adding that firing Comey “might even lengthen out the investigation.
>        ”
> 5. The appointment of a Special Counsel and efforts to remove him.
>
>    - On May 17, 2017, the
>        Acting Attorney General for the Russia investigation appointed a Special Counsel to conduct the
>        investigation and related matters. The President reacted to news that a Special Counsel had been
>        appointed by telling advisors that it was “the end of his presidency” and demanding that Sessions
>        resign. Sessions submitted his resignation, but the President ultimately did not accept it. The
>        President told aides that the Special Counsel had conflicts of interest and suggested that the Special
>        Counsel therefore could not serve. The President’s advisors told him the asserted conflicts were
>        meritless and had already been considered by the Department of Justice.
>        On June 14, 2017, the media reported that the Special Counsel’s Office was investigating
>        whether the President had obstructed justice. Press reports called this “a major turning point” in
>        the investigation: while Comey had told the President he was not under investigation, following
>        Comey’s firing, the President now was under investigation. The President reacted to this news
>        with a series of tweets criticizing the Department of Justice and the Special Counsel’s
>        investigation. On June 17, 2017, the President called McGahn at home and directed him to call
>        the Acting Attorney General and say that the Special Counsel had conflicts of interest and must be
>        removed. McGahn did not carry out the direction, however, deciding that he would resign rather
>        than trigger what he regarded as a potential Saturday Night Massacre.
> 6. Efforts to curtail the Special Counsel's investigation.
>
>    - Two days after directing McGahn
>        to have the Special Counsel removed, the President made another attempt to affect the course of
>        the Russia investigation. On June 19, 2017, the President met one-on-one in the Oval Office with
>        his former campaign manager Corey Lewandowski, a trusted advisor outside the government, and
>        dictated a message for Lewandowski to deliver to Sessions. The message said that Sessions should
>        publicly announce that, notwithstanding his recusal from the Russia investigation, the investigation
>        was “very unfair” to the President, the President had done nothing wrong, and Sessions planned to 
>        meet with the Special Counsel and “let [him] move forward with investigating election meddling
>        for future elections.
>        ” Lewandowski said he understood what the President wanted Sessions to do.
>        One month later, in another private meeting with Lewandowski on July 19, 2017, the
>        President asked about the status of his message for Sessions to limit the Special Counsel
>        investigation to future election interference. Lewandowski told the President that the message
>        would be delivered soon. Hours after that meeting, the President publicly criticized Sessions in an
>        interview with the New York Times, and then issued a series of tweets making it clear that
>        Sessions’s job was in jeopardy. Lewandowski did not want to deliver the President’s message
>        personally, so he asked senior White House official Rick Dearborn to deliver it to Sessions.
>        Dearborn was uncomfortable with the task and did not follow through.
> 7. Efforts to prevent public disclosure of evidence.
>
>    - In the summer of 2017, the President
>        learned that media outlets were asking questions about the June 9, 2016 meeting at Trump Tower
>        between senior campaign officials, including Donald Trump Jr., and a Russian lawyer who was
>        said to be offering damaging information about Hillary Clinton as “part of Russia and its
>        government’s support for Mr. Trump.
>        ” On several occasions, the President directed aides not to
>        publicly disclose the emails setting up the June 9 meeting, suggesting that the emails would not
>        leak and that the number of lawyers with access to them should be limited. Before the emails
>        became public, the President edited a press statement for Trump Jr. by deleting a line that
>        acknowledged that the meeting was with “an individual who [Trump Jr.] was told might have
>        information helpful to the campaign” and instead said only that the meeting was about adoptions
>        of Russian children. When the press asked questions about the President’s involvement in Trump
>        Jr.
>        ’s statement, the President’s personal lawyer repeatedly denied the President had played any
>        role.
> 8. Further efforts to have the Attorney General take control of the investigation.
>
>    - In early
>        summer 2017, the President called Sessions at home and again asked him to reverse his recusal
>        from the Russia investigation. Sessions did not reverse his recusal. In October 2017, the President
>        met privately with Sessions in the Oval Office and asked him to “take [a] look” at investigating
>        Clinton. In December 2017, shortly after Flynn pleaded guilty pursuant to a cooperation
>        agreement, the President met with Sessions in the Oval Office and suggested, according to notes
>        taken by a senior advisor, that if Sessions unrecused and took back supervision of the Russia
>        investigation, he would be a “hero.
>        ” The President told Sessions,
>        “I’m not going to do anything
>        or direct you to do anything. I just want to be treated fairly.
>        ” In response, Sessions volunteered
>        that he had never seen anything “improper” on the campaign and told the President there was a
>        “whole new leadership team” in place. He did not unrecuse.
> 9. Efforts to have McGahn deny that the President had ordered him to have the Special
>      Counsel removed.
>
>    - In early 2018, the press reported that the President had directed McGahn to have the Special Counsel removed in June 2017 and that McGahn had threatened to resign rather
>        than carry out the order. The President reacted to the news stories by directing White House
>        officials to tell McGahn to dispute the story and create a record stating he had not been ordered to
>        have the Special Counsel removed. McGahn told those officials that the media reports were
>        accurate in stating that the President had directed McGahn to have the Special Counsel removed.
>        The President then met with McGahn in the Oval Office and again pressured him to deny the
>        reports. In the same meeting, the President also asked McGahn why he had told the Special
>        Counsel about the President’s effort to remove the Special Counsel and why McGahn took notes
>        of his conversations with the President. McGahn refused to back away from what he remembered
>        happening and perceived the President to be testing his mettle.
> 10. Conduct towards Flynn, Manafort, [redacted; HOM].
>
>     - After Flynn withdrew from a joint defense
>         agreement with the President and began cooperating with the government, the President’s personal
>         counsel left a message for Flynn’s attorneys reminding them of the President’s warm feelings
>         towards Flynn, which he said “still remains,
>         ” and asking for a “heads up” if Flynn knew
>         “information that implicates the President.
>         ” When Flynn’s counsel reiterated that Flynn could no
>         longer share information pursuant to a joint defense agreement, the President’s personal counsel
>         said he would make sure that the President knew that Flynn’s actions reflected “hostility” towards
>         the President.
>        During Manafort’s prosecution and when the jury in his criminal, trial was
>         deliberating, the President praised Manafort in public, said that Manafort was being treated
>         unfairly, and declined to rule out a pardon. After Manafort was convicted, the President called
>         Manafort “a brave man” for refusing to “break” and said that “flipping” “almost ought to be outlawed.” [large redaction; harm to ongoing matter]
> 11. Conduct involving Michael Cohen.
>
>     - The President’s conduct towards Michael Cohen, a
>         former Trump Organization executive, changed from praise for Cohen when he falsely minimized
>         the President’s involvement in the Trump Tower Moscow project, to castigation of Cohen when
>         he became a cooperating witness.
>        From September 2015 to June 2016, Cohen had pursued the
>         Trump Tower Moscow project on behalf of the Trump Organization and had briefed candidate
>         Trump on the project numerous times, including discussing whether Trump should travel to Russia
>         to advance the deal.
>        In 2017, Cohen provided false testimony to Congress about the project,
>         including stating that he had only briefed Trump on the project three times and never discussed
>         travel to Russia with him, in an effort to adhere to a “party line” that Cohen said was developed to
>         minimize the President’s connections to Russia. While preparing for his congressional testimony,
>         Cohen had extensive discussions with the President’s personal counsel, who, according to Cohen,
>         said that Cohen should “stay on message” and not contradict the President.
>        After the FBI searched
>         Cohen’s home and office in April 2018, the President publicly asserted that Cohen would not
>         “flip,
>         ” contacted him directly to tell him to “stay strong,
>         ” and privately passed messages of support
>         to him. Cohen also discussed pardons with the President’s personal counsel and believed that if
>         he stayed on message he would be taken care of. But after Cohen began cooperating with the
>         government in the summer of 2018, the President publicly criticized him, called him a “rat,
>         ” and
>         suggested that his family members had committed crimes.

#### Why the president wasn't prosecuted for obstruction of justice

In reply to your comment under Fizz's answer:

> As far as I understand, Mueller didn't indict Trump because he didn't think that he had the authority to do so, not because he didn't see cases of obstruction.

The executive summary ends with the following conclusion (on page 8 of the second volume, page 220 in the linked pdf):

> **Conclusion**
>
> Because we determined not to make a traditional prosecutorial judgment, we did not draw
>   ultimate conclusions about the President’s conduct. The evidence we obtained about the
>   President’s actions and intent presents difficult issues that would need to be resolved if we were
>   making a traditional prosecutorial judgment. At the same time, if we had confidence after a
>   thorough investigation of the facts that the President clearly did not commit obstruction of justice,
>   we would so state. Based on the facts and the applicable legal standards, we are unable to reach
>   that judgment. Accordingly, while this report does not conclude that the President committed a
>   crime, it also does not exonerate him.

Note that pages 7 and 8 of the second volume go into more detail when it comes to the decision not to prosecute the president for obstruction of justice, but I think the conclusion suffices here.

Comment: This answer continues the false narrative that the Mueller report states that the president is guilty of obstruction of justice.  The report says no such things. It list possible occasions where obstruction MAY HAVE OCCURRED.  And further expresses that the Mueller team did not test if the incidents pass the test of obstruction because THEY WERE NOT ALLOWED TO. Further, they state that they would have found him innocent of obstruction if they would know he was innocent but they can't because THEY WERE NOT ALLOWED TO LOOK INTO IT.

Comment: @FrankCedeno please look at the following line in my last quote *"At the same time, if we had confidence after a thorough investigation of the facts that the President clearly did not commit obstruction of justice, we would so state. "*. This was a thorough investigation, and based on that quote, logic dictates that the authors *"that the President clearly did not commit obstruction of justice"*. As for the part where you allege that I say the president is guilty, please indicate where in my answer I say that. The only time I use that word is in direct quotes from the report.